# Replacing strings in Word through VB. Works on first string only

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to replace a string in a Word .doc file using Visual Basic, Visual Studio 2012. This code works for the first line that contains `<<FileNumber>>`. What's the trick to make it work for the rest? Thanks.

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    oWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\" + txtReportFolder.Text + "\" + txtReportNumber.Text + "\Form A.doc")
    oWord.Documents("Form A.doc").Activate()
    oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument
    Dim oRange = oDoc.Content
    oRange.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<FileNumber>>", ReplaceWith:=txtReportNumber.Text)
    oRange.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<OCode1>>", ReplaceWith:="488")
    oRange.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<Text>>", ReplaceWith:="Loss")
    oRange.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<EDP1>>", ReplaceWith:="16G2-M")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Add this between all executes:

```
oRange = oDoc.Content
```

I would then also add these:

```
    oDoc.Save()
    oWord.Quit()
```